# I tried to use map in problem but it seems wrong i can t find problem. Could you help me?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    map<string,string> mym;
    int n;
    string s,a,r;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        getline(cin,s);
        getline(cin,a);
        mym.insert(pair<string,string>(s,a));
        s.erase();
        a.erase();
    } 
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        getline(cin,r);
        if(mym.count(r)!=0){
            cout << r << '=' << mym.at(r) <<endl;
        }
        else cout << "Not found" << endl;
        r.clear();
    } 
   return 0;
}
```

## I tried to use map in problem but it seems wrong i can t find problem. Could you help me?

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem

## input

> sam 99912222
>     tom 11122222
>   harry 12299933
>   sam
>   edward
>   harry

### my result

> Not found
>   =sam 99912222
>   =sam 99912222

Comment: Your input should start with `3` to indicate such that `n` is properly assigned. Is that the case?

Comment: Hint for future questions: Please always explain what you are trying to do and what you are expecting from your code. Don't use links as an explanation, since they can expire. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

cin >> n;

Will consume the number of the input, but won't consume the subsequent end of line that follows before the next string.

So instead of `cin >> n`, do this:

```
string tmp;
getline(cin, tmp);
n = atoi(tmp.c_str());
```

There's probably other ways to do this.

Some other code cleanup as follows:

```
int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    map<string,string> mym;
    int n;
    string tmp;

    cin >> tmp;
    n = atoi(tmp.c_str());

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        string s, a;
        getline(cin,s);
        getline(cin,a);
        mym[s] = a;
    } 
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        string r;
        getline(cin,r);
        auto itor = mym.find(r);
        if(itor != mym.end())
            cout << r << '=' << itor->second <<endl;
        }
        else {
           cout << "Not found" << endl;
        }
    } 
   return 0;
}
```